# JavaScript: Travel to another page to get specific info that's not on the current page?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have JavaScript that runs on page A.

Page B contains some specific piece of info that I would like to display,  As an example:

```
<script tye="text/javascript">
  var specificPieceOfInfo = "The secret number is 10"
</script>
```

Page A knows the URL to page b (let's just say its www.pageB.com)

Is there a way for page A to get access to `specificPieceOfInfo` from page B? I know in Python I could use something like the requests library, but I'm not sure what I can do with JavaScript.

Comment: Might be a problem with same origin policy. You could try to use for example a PHP script as a proxy or perhaps a quirky iframe approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those pages are on the same domain, you could load the other page into an `iframe`, and then access the global variable via `contentWindow`.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src = '/pageB.html';

iframe.onload = function() {
    var specificPieceOfInfo = iframe.contentWindow.specificPieceOfInfo;

    console.log(specificPieceOfInfo);

    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
}

iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

If the pages are on separate domains, this will not be possible because of [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: They are on the same domain.  I tried doing this but I'm a little confused.

As soon as I set the src, should iframe's contentWindow be pointing to the other page?

Your sample isn't working from me as it says iframe.contentWindow is null

Comment: @TrolliOlli `contentWindow` won't be set until after it is added to the document (`document.body.appendChild`). The `specificPieceOfInfo` variable also won't be set until after the code in the page runs (I used `onload` to wait, but other options are possible).